# UICollectionView clipsToBounds=false is not working correctly

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, clipstobounds

I am trying to make below effect using UICollectionView and its working fine.

[image]

However when I scroll left and right sometimes left or right cell is hiding. I can't see 3 rows, I just see 2 rows. Either left or right gets hided something like below.

[image]

I know the solution for this is `collectionview.clipsToBounds = false`, however cells are getting hided.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    print("viewWillLayoutSubviews")
    hotelsCV.clipsToBounds = false
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Below is my collection view frame.

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: i can't see whats wrong in the pictures can you point out which one

Comment: Personally, I've been through the pain of implementing collection views as you're doing, and I recommend using https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView which will save you a lot of time doing it yourself.

But if you do want to do it yourself, you'll need to enlarge the collection view frame to be full screen, and configure scrollview delegate methods, etc. etc.

See https://medium.com/@shaibalassiano/tutorial-horizontal-uicollectionview-with-paging-9421b479ee94

Comment: @Tobi : Check second image... I have updated question

Comment: @Tobi : Any update? did you see the issue?

Comment: @FahimParkar yes i did, i have other things in my hands but asap as i can answer i will if someone didn't help by then

Comment: @MohmmadS : Did you have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will resolve your issue.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix for me

Comment: can you explain more what this will do?

Comment: If you remove an edge value from this property, the system does not lay out your content underneath other bars on that same edge. In addition, the system provides a default background so that translucent bars have an appropriate appearance. The window’s root view controller does not react to this property.

You can refer it in Apple's official documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621515-edgesforextendedlayout)